# Array Spread Operator in Pure Function

Tags: javascript, redux, pure-function

In Redux Tutorial, they have used array spread operator a lot for writing reducers(which have to be pure functions) . Go through the following script.

```
let a = {
  b : "ddff",
  c : "adxas"
}

let c = {
  b : "ssdds",
  c : "asdxasdsad"
}

let d = [];

d.push(a);
d.push(c);

console.log(d);

const pureFunc = (arr,b,c) => {
  return [...arr, { b , c}];
}

let n = pureFunc(d,"daaaa","sdadad");
console.log(n);
d[0].b = "Hello";
console.log(n)
```

Is the function "pureFunc" is a proper pure function. Mutations on array d are getting reflected in object n.

Comment: I’m not sure what your question is exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `pureFunc` is pure. The mutation does not occur within `pureFunc`.

One of the most common and basic pure functions is the identity function:

`let identity = x => x;`

So, if we pass that an object, we'll get the same object back. We can modify it *after the fact*, but that doesn't make `identity` impure, because `identity` isn't doing the mutation.

Basically, pure functions only need to satisfy two requirements:

1. They always produce the same output given the same input
2. They do not cause side effects